# SQL for each row corresponsing to every other row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is like this:

```
Name    day1 day2 day3 day4 day5
charles    1    0    0    1    1
bob        1    1    1    0    0
tom        0    0    0    1    1
```

Constraints : columns are about 1000
I want an output like :

```
        charles bob tom 
charles  3     1    2
bob      1     3    0
tom      2     0    2
```

i.e. the number of 1's that are common between each of them. What will the sql be corresponding to this ?

Comment: This looks like a problem of poor design

Answer (score 2):

A normalised schema might look something like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,day INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(name,day)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('charles' ,  1),
('bob'      , 1),
('bob'      , 2),
('bob'      , 3),
('charles'  , 4),
('tom'      , 4),
('charles'  , 5),
('tom'      , 5);
```

Your query would then look like this...

```
SELECT x.name
     , y.name
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.name < x.name 
   AND y.day = x.day
 GROUP 
    BY x.name
     , y.name;

+---------+---------+-------+
| name    | name    | total |
+---------+---------+-------+
| charles | bob     |     1 |
| tom     | charles |     2 |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

...and the rest of the problem is a display issue, best resolved in application code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a horrible schema for this -- as Strawberry points out.

You are basically stuck with a query like this:

```
select t1.name, t2.name,
       sum( (t1.day1 = t2.day1) +
            (t1.day2 = t2.day2) +
            . . .
          ) as days_in_common
from t t1 cross join
     t t2;
```

You can generate the code in a spreadsheet.

Note that this does not pivot the columns.  That may not even be possible, depending on the number of rows in your original table.